# How to invoke saved request handler of a previous request from a filter for Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, razor-pages

I have the following razor page filter class:

```cs
public class TwoFactorPageFilter : IAsyncPageFilter
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationSession _session;
    private HttpContext _httpContext;

    public TwoFactorPageFilter(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationSession session)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _session     = session;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext pageContext)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext pageContext, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        _httpContext = pageContext.HttpContext;

        await InitTwoFactorLock();

        if ( RequestRequires2fa() )
        {
            SavePostActionState(pageContext);
            _httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/LoginWith2fa");
        }
        else if ( _session.Recent2fa )
        {
            // HELP: how to call original razor page handler here, using properties
            // saved to _session, after user successfully verified using 2FA?
        }

        await next.Invoke();
    }

    private async Task InitTwoFactorLock()
    {
        IdentityUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContext.User);
        // initialize the 2FA lock default value based on if the user enabled/disabled 2FA login
        _session.TwoFactorLockOn = user is not null ? await _userManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user) : false;
    }

    private bool RequestRequires2fa()
    {
        // only POST requests would ever need to be verified
        if ( _httpContext.Request.Method != "POST" ) return false;

        // don't bother if user is not even authenticated
        if ( ! _httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return false;

        // if the 2FA lock session variable is turned off, then do not require 2FA verification
        if ( ! _session.TwoFactorLockOn ) return false;

        return RouteNeeds2fa();
    }

    private bool RouteNeeds2fa()
    {
        var paths = new List<string> {"/Account/Change", "/Account/Remove", "/Security/Update",};
        return paths.Contains(_httpContext.Request.Path);
    }

    private void SavePostActionState(PageHandlerExecutingContext pageContext)
    {
        // save all relevant data to session state
        _session.OriginalHandlerMethod = pageContext.HandlerMethod;
        _session.OriginalModelState    = pageContext.ModelState;
        // HELP: what else do I need to save to the session state here?
    }

}
```

The idea is to redirect `POST` requests hitting certain routes/endpoints to a 2FA verification page instead, for improved security. The redirection part currently works well enough.

The way I'd like this to work is to save the request handler state (i.e. `SavePostActionState`) to `_session` (an implementation of `ISession`) when the original `POST` request comes in and got redirected to the `/Identity/Account/LoginWith2fa` endpoint. Then when the user successfully verifies using their 2FA authenticator, `_session.Recent2fa` would be set to `true` in the `LoginWith2fa` page handler, and I'd retrieve the saved handler state info for the original request sent by the user, and perform that action.

But given the properties/objects made available to me through the `PageHandlerExecutedContext`, such as `HandlerInstance`, `HandlerMethod`, `ModelState`, `Result`, etc. I'm still unsure about how to compose them in order to "re-invoke" the original request.

Comment: How would you handle POST requests with large bodies? Read and hold the request stream in the memory? You have to read the body, or it would be lost. I think you'd be better off keeping things simple: keep the state in the UI, perform 2FA in a popup if you don't want to lose the form state. If it succeeds, then perform the actual request

Comment: @abdusco good point about large bodies, though in the current scope of the application, this is unlikely to be a problem, b/c all user POST'd data are validated to be less than a modest size. The way you suggest is more or less how it works currently. However, this has lead to quite a bit of duplicated code in each handler for all actions that require this 2FA verification step, and otherwise unneeded dependencies in their respective `PageModel` classes. It also makes more sense from a business logic perspective for these actions to not have to care about whether they should check 2FA or not.